# Can I delete all rows but only left one row?

Tags: mysql

Can I delete all row in my table but only left 1 Record?
speak it freely like `DELETE FROM table_name UNLESS id='5'`
but the id value is a random number. 
Thanks,

Comment: You want to delete all but one _arbitrary_ row? Why? Which one? You have to decide which one to delete. So come up with a rule... even if it's by first performing a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` without an `ORDER BY` to obtain details of the row not to delete.

Comment: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id != 'number'

Comment: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id <> n; where n is any integer you choose to nominate & as n is an integer don't use quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webster is right

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id != 'number';
```

Or:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id NOT LIKE 'number';
```

Comment: operator `!=` doesn't works for all SQL databases so you should tell them to use <>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave only one random row and you have a unique id, then:

```
delete t
    from t cross join
         (select id from t order by rand() limit 1
         ) tt
    where t.id <> tt.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id NOT IN = (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM [your_table_name] WHERE id != [your_id];
```